# Rankin-Selberg bound on coefficients

Tags: number-theory, automorphic-forms

For an automorphic L-functions, often there is a bound refereed to by Ramanujan on average, where the coefficients satisfy
$$\sum_{n<x} \lambda(n) \ll x^{1+\varepsilon}$$

Why is this bound true and how does it relate to Rankin-Selberg method? Is it known in general or only for some specific/low-degree L-functions?

Comment: I don't know much about this but Ramanujan is known when there is an algebraic representation so you can apply Weil's RH to bound the Frobenius eigenvalues (the Satake parameters), then it should be known when you construct a 3rd L-function from 2 such L-functions like in Rankin Selberg.

Comment: @reuns But this is not known for e.g. $GL(3)$, right? or more generally higher rank groups

Answer (score 2):

Let $\pi$ be an automorphic representation of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q}})$, which I will assume for simplicity is everywhere unramified. Following Goldfeld's book (*Automorphic Forms and $L$-Functions for the group $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$*), we write $A(m_1,\ldots,m_{n-1})$ for the Hecke eigenvalues of $\pi$, so that for $\Re(s) > 1$,
$$L(s,\pi) = \sum_{m = 1}^{\infty} \frac{A(1,\ldots,1,m)}{m^s}.$$
Then for $\Re(s) > 1$,
$$L(s,\pi \times \widetilde{\pi}) = \zeta(ns) \sum_{m_1,\ldots,m_{n-1} = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\left|A(m_1,\ldots,m_{n-1})\right|^2}{(m_1^{n-1} \cdots m_{n-1})^s}.$$
This has a simple pole at $s = 1$, so that (by, say, any standard Tauberian theorem)
$$\sum_{m_1^{n-1} \cdots m_{n-1} \leq x} \left|A(m_1,\ldots,m_{n-1})\right|^2 \sim \operatorname*{Res}_{s=1} \frac{L(s,\pi \times \widetilde{\pi})}{\zeta(ns)} x.$$
In particular,
$$\sum_{m \leq x} |A(1,\ldots,1,m)|^2 \ll x,$$
and hence via the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,
$$\sum_{m \leq x} |A(1,\ldots,1,m)| \ll x.$$

Answer (score 2):

As a followup to [Peter's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4469094/9754), I wanted to note that "Ramanujan on average" concerns
$$ \sum_{n \leq X} \lvert \lambda(n) \rvert \ll X, $$
which is slightly different than
$$ \sum_{n \leq X} \lambda(n). \tag{1}$$
Typically the conjectured bound in $(1)$ is much, much smaller. For example, if $\lambda(n)$ are the Hecke eigenvalues of a cuspidal Hecke eigenform on $\mathrm{GL}(2)$, then it is conjectured that
$$ \sum_{n \leq X} \lambda(n) \ll X^{\frac{1}{4} + \epsilon} $$
and currently known that
$$ \sum_{n \leq X} \lambda(n) \ll X^{\frac{1}{3}}.$$
These are analogous results to bounds for the Gauss circle problem.

More generally, if $\lambda(n)$ are the coefficients of the Godement-Jacquet $L$-function of a generic irreducible unitary automorphic representation of $\mathrm{GL}(n, \mathbb{R})$ (i.e. $A(1, 1, \ldots, n)$ as in Peter's answer), then one can show that
$$ \sum_{n \leq X} \lambda(n) \ll X^{1 - \frac{2}{d(d+1)} + \epsilon}. $$
This bound follows from a "standard" technical argument of Landau, but it's possible that more is known.

With absolute values, the Ramanujan-on-average bound $O(X)$ is the best one can hope for.